# XNA Scale and Render Targets

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, rendertargets, scale

I'm working on a top down Strategy/RPG/Tower Defense XNA Game for Windows, and I'm running into an issue while scaling.

My display mode is 1680 X 1050, and that is what I'm setting the PreferredBackBuffer width and height to.

What I'm finding is that when I use my camera object to zoom in and out (changing the scale on a matrix that is passed to the SpriteBatch.Begin method, it changes the scale of my sprites... but I'm still confined to the BackBuffer (0,0,1680,1050)...

Can I use something like a RenderTarget to extend the actual area that is accessible when zooming/panning across the "map"?

I'm looking at making it something like 5000 X 3125...

Any thoughts/examples of how I should approach this?

I've added a video of what I'm experiencing... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIiAeXbAnec

For the record I have also posted this question on [Stack Exchange - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510535/xna-scale-and-render-targets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the coordinates you are getting from `Mouse.GetState()` always fall within the bounds of the screen (ie: 0 < x < 1680 and 0 < y < 1050).

This is normal.

The transformation matrix you are using is taking coordinates in "**world space**" and putting them in "**client space**" (which is the space that `SpriteBatch` then uses to project sprites onto the screen).

`Mouse.GetState()` also returns coordinates in client space. What you want is to find what position those client coordinates represent in world space. So what you have to do is *reverse* the transformation. Here is some (untested) code that shows you how:

```
MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
Matrix transform = whatever;
Matrix inverseTransform = Matrix.Invert(transform);
Vector2 clientMouse = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
Vector2 worldMouse = Vector2.Transform(clientMouse, inverseTransform);
```

(Note: If you get NaN errors, make sure you're not scaling your Z coordinate down to zero, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3689571/165500).)

Comment: perfect.  sorry it took so long to respond but that did it... I created a new method in my camera object that returns the inverse of the matrix and i just set my mouse position object to always be the inverse of the the transformation... works perfectly!